# Load svg through react: currentColor from CSS variable

Tags: css, reactjs

I am loading svgs through react: my problem now would be to load it using currentColor from CSS variable

```
import SvgItem from '-!svg-react-loader!./item.svg';

const MyComponent: React.FunctionComponent = () => {
  return (
      <div className="svg-color" style={{color:"var('--color-primary')", fill: "var('--color-primary')"}}>
            <SvgItem />
      </div>
   );
}
```

It works using style={{color:"blue"}} but not using the CSS var.

```
<svg fill="currentColor" >
    <path d="M170.056 30.0762L97.089"/>
</svg>
```

My only way now is to create a react component for each SVG file...

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

It works for both css variables and `currentColor`, I think the reason it doesn't work is because your `d` of the SVG path is corrupted(if you didn't crop it).

```html
<div style="--color-primary: red;">
    <svg fill="var(--color-primary)" width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 1 1">
        <path d="M.5,0 L1,1 H0" />
    </svg>
</div>

<div style="--color-primary: blue;">
    <svg fill="var(--color-primary)" width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 1 1">
        <path d="M.5,0 L1,1 H0" />
    </svg>
</div>

<div style="--color-primary: green; color: var(--color-primary);">
    <svg fill="currentColor" width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 1 1">
        <path d="M.5,0 L1,1 H0" />
    </svg>
</div>
```

Then you can just pass in the `color` props to assign color dynamically:

```js
import SvgItem from '-!svg-react-loader!./item.svg';

const MyComponent: React.FunctionComponent = ({ color }) => {
  return (
      <div className="svg-color" style={{ color }}>
            <SvgItem />
      </div>
   );
}
```

For the **SvgItem**:

```
<svg fill="currentColor" >
    <path d="M170.056 30.0762L97.089"/>
</svg>
```

To assign its color:

```js
<MyComponent color="red" />
```